# How can I send an Email to myself using REST API

Tags: rest, http, email

I'm building a React app and want to make a customer contact form. The client fills out a simple form and then I receive an email. I don't want to write an API because it's a very small task. I thought that there are ready-made solutions, but all I find is services for sending emails to clients, but I need it the other way around.

Comment: You need some kind of API, there is no way around it. Without an API you cannot send email from a web application, all you can do is make HTTP calls, which is insufficient for email which uses SMTP. You *need* server side code.

Comment: Of course I need service side code. But I don't want implement it. I'd like to use ready third party servise for pay.